# Solving this system of equations in $\mathbb{Z}/19\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: ring-theory, field-theory, modular-arithmetic

I have this question but I am not sure how to proceed on it.

> Find all values $a$ for which the system of the two equations
>   $$xy=a, \quad x+y=1$$
>   has a solution in $\mathbb{Z}/19\mathbb{Z}$. Is there such an $a$ for which there is a unique solution?

I am not sure if the $a$ has to be in $\mathbb{Z}/19\mathbb{Z}$ or if the solutions are, so far I have $x-x^2=a$ and $y=1-x$.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean when you ask if $a$ has to be in $\mathbb{Z}/(19)$, since it doesn't really matter if $a$ is in $\mathbb{Z}$ or $\mathbb{Z}/(19)$ since the equation is mod 19 regardless.

Now note that since you have $x-x^2=a$, then we can complete the square to get
$x^2-x + 5 = (x-10)^2 = 5-a$. Thus we need 
$$ \left(\frac{5-a}{19}\right)=1$$
in order to have two solutions, or $a=5$ to have a single unique solution
of $x=10$.

Comment: First of all thanks a lot for your answer. Now I am not sure I understand properly why you take the (x-10)^2 and where it comes from ? (x-10)^2 is not equal to x^2-x+5, is it ? Or is it because it's mod 19 ?

Comment: @ThéodoreRozencwajg Yep, it's because it's mod 19, $100\equiv 5 \pmod{19}$, and $-20 \equiv -1 \pmod{19}$ as well. Also it just comes from the usual completing the square, $\frac{-1}{2}\equiv -10 \pmod{19}$.

Comment: Okay I understand, but is it correct to put equal signs still ? or do I have to use the equivalence signs ? (I'm talking about when you complete the squares), also for the 2 solutions, do we get a=-14 mod 19 ?

Comment: @ThéodoreRozencwajg It depends on your convention. I tend to use equals signs when working mod a certain number and the number doesn't change, but technically the congruences are more proper. So (mod 19) there are 9 choices for $a$ that have 2 solutions for $x$ each (where $5-a$ is a nonzero perfect square modulo 19), and one solution for $a$ which has a unique solution for $x$ (when $a=5\equiv -14\pmod{19}$).

Comment: So we have (5-a)/19 = 1 mod 19 right ? What are the 9 solutions, I am not sure I can see what they are.

Comment: I also don't really understand how we get that (5-a)/19 = 1 from completing the square before.

Comment: So that's not a fraction, I should explain, sorry.

Comment: That's the Legendre Symbol: http://www.wikiwand.com/en/Legendre_symbol.